# Error reading many .img files from a folder in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have 100 .img files that I am trying to read from a directory using the following code:

```
srcFiles = dir('/Users/Adrian/Documents/Foam_Data/ssd0/2013-10-25_09-01-12/000000/*.img'); % the folder in which ur images exists

for i = 1:100   % length(srcFiles)

     filename = srcFiles(i).name;
    fid = fopen(filename);
    image = fread(fid, 2048*2048, 'uint8=>uint8');
    fclose(fid);
    image = reshape(image, 2048, 2048);
    figure;
    imshow(image);

end
```

The `'/Users/Adrian/Documents/Foam_Data/ssd0/2013-10-25_09-01-12/000000/'` is the path of my directory where my .img files are located. It seems I have an error in defining the file identifier, but I can't tell what am I missing:

```
Error using fread
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in sequenceimage (line 32)
    image = fread(fid, 2048*2048, 'uint8=>uint8');
```

Can anyone help me fix the error?

Comment: what is the actual output of the call to `fid` ? i.e. what outputs when you remove the semi-colon?

Comment: Since we have fixed this issue, please consider accepting my answer here.  It signifies to the StackOverflow community that you no longer need help in this regard.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you are getting that error is because `dir` returns **relative** names to each file listed, not **absolute** paths to each file.  As such, by doing `srcFiles(i).name`, you would only get the file name itself - not the **full path to the file**.

As such, you need to append the directory on top of the file itself when making the call to `fopen`.

To make things more flexible, place the directory in a separate string so that you only have to make modifications to your code in one place instead of two places.

Very simply:

```
%// Change here
loc = '/Users/Adrian/Documents/Foam_Data/ssd0/2013-10-25_09-01-12/000000/';

%// Change here
srcFiles = dir([loc '*.img']); % the folder in which ur images exists

for i = 1:100   % length(srcFiles)

     filename = srcFiles(i).name;

    %// Change here!
    fid = fopen([loc filename]);
    image = fread(fid, 2048*2048, 'uint8=>uint8');
    fclose(fid);
    image = reshape(image, 2048, 2048);
    figure;
    imshow(image);

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this before, and I don't get any errors, indeed. But my images are dark, and I don't know why, because I am able to generate single images, but when I try multiples ones, I get dark images.

Comment: I get a warning telling that the image is too big to fit the screen, and it only displays it at 33%.

Comment: Interesting. Could you upload one of these images? I'd let to see for myself what's wrong. Don't think it has anything to do with the code. It may be the way the pixels are laid out. Are these pixels row or column major in layout?